# Convert C# function call to F# - Create empty object array

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

How to convert the following function call to F# call?

```cs
Hashtable table = (Hashtable) cookieJar.GetType().InvokeMember("m_domainTable",
                                                                BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                                BindingFlags.GetField |
                                                                BindingFlags.Instance,
                                                                null,
                                                                cookieJar,
                                                                new object[] {});
```

The following convert F# code has error on `new Object[]`

```
let cs = cc.GetType().InvokeMember("m_domainTable", BindingFlags.NonPublic |||
                                                                BindingFlags.GetField |||
                                                                BindingFlags.Instance,
                                                                null,
                                                                cc,
                                                                new Object[] {}))
```

Comment: At what exact point are you stuck?

Comment: So why not post your attempt at the F#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a new empty array in F#, you just need to write `[| |]`, so your code should be:

```
let flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.GetField ||| BindingFlags.Instance
let cs = cc.GetType().InvokeMember("m_domainTable", flags, null, cc, [| |])
```